# The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existingappcompat_v7.jar

Tags: android

After updating my SDK version, I have been getting lot of issues from appcompat.The issue now i have is The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing libraryappcompat_v7/bin/appcompat_v7.jar'  Build Path Problem. I tried several deferent ways to fix this but couldn't. Help is appriciated

[image]

Comment: It looks like the `bin` folder of the `appcompat_v7` project is empty.

Comment: yeah. It does not generate such a .jar file and it is not mentioned on anyway on internet as well. Everyone is referring to android-support-c7-support.jar not this. How can i get the relevant jar file in to the bin folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the issue was java version once i updated it, things got back to normal